# ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator. SAS

Tags: sas

I am pretty new to SAS, I am trying to see which songs/artists/albums have appeared most on my spotify most played csv's (2017-2020). I am getting stuck very early on trying to just set the 2017 csv as a data set. Is there anything anyone can see that I am doing wrong? Seems like this step should be pretty straight forward.

```
data Spotify_2017;
infile='C:\Users\your_top_songs_2017.csv' dlm=’09’x dsd firstobs=2;
input Track URI Track Name Artist URI Artist Name Album URI Album Name Album Release Date Disc Number Track Number Track Duration Explicit Popularity Added By Added At;
run;
```

and here is the log:

```
1                                                          The SAS System                             10:18 Friday, January 15, 2021

1          ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
2          OPTIONS PAGENO=MIN;
3          %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL='Spotify.sas';
4          %LET _CLIENTPROCESSFLOWNAME='Standalone Not In Project';
5          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH='';
6          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATHHOST='';
7          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME='';
8          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE='C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Spotify\Spotify.sas';
9          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILEHOST='USRDUL-PC0NNXU1';
10         
11         ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
12         OPTIONS DEV=SVG;
13         GOPTIONS XPIXELS=0 YPIXELS=0;
14         %macro HTML5AccessibleGraphSupported;
15             %if %_SAS_VERCOMP_FV(9,4,4, 0,0,0) >= 0 %then ACCESSIBLE_GRAPH;
16         %mend;
17         FILENAME EGHTML TEMP;
18         ODS HTML5(ID=EGHTML) FILE=EGHTML
19             OPTIONS(BITMAP_MODE='INLINE')
20             %HTML5AccessibleGraphSupported
21             ENCODING='utf-8'
22             STYLE=HtmlBlue
23             NOGTITLE
24             NOGFOOTNOTE
25             GPATH=&sasworklocation
26         ;
NOTE: Writing HTML5(EGHTML) Body file: EGHTML
27         
28         data Spotify_2017;
29         infile='C:\Users\pcardella\Desktop\Spotify\C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Spotify\your_top_songs_2017.csv' dlm=’09’x dsd
                                                                                                                  ___
                                                                                                                  388
                                                                                                                  76
29       ! firstobs=2;
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

30         input Track URI Track Name Artist URI Artist Name Album URI Album Name Album Release Date Disc Number Track Number Track
30       ! Duration Explicit Popularity Added By Added At;
31         run;

ERROR: No DATALINES or INFILE statement.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.SPOTIFY_2017 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 16 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
      

32         
33         %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL=;
34         %LET _CLIENTPROCESSFLOWNAME=;
35         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH=;
36         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATHHOST=;
37         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME=;
38         %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
39         %LET _SASPROGRAMFILEHOST=;
2                                                          The SAS System                             10:18 Friday, January 15, 2021

40         
41         ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
42         ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
43         
44         
45         QUIT; RUN;
46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`infile` is a statement and does not need an equals sign. The syntax is:

`infile 'file location here' <options>;`

```
data Spotify_2017;
    infile 'C:\Users\your_top_songs_2017.csv' dlm=’09’x dsd firstobs=2;
    input Track URI Track Name Artist URI Artist Name Album URI Album Name Album Release Date Disc Number Track Number Track Duration Explicit Popularity Added By Added At;
run;
```

One way to help learn importing raw files using the data step is to use `proc import`. `proc import` will import the data and generate data step code for you in the log when importing csv files. You can study it to see how it works and try to replicate it.

```
proc import 
    file = 'C:\Users\your_top_songs_2017.csv'
    out  = spotify_2017
    dbms = csv
    replace;
run;
```

Also, a great option to help make logs more readable in Enterprise Guide is to disable autogenerated code. Go to Tools -> Options -> Results -> General -> uncheck "Show generated wrapper code in SAS log"